# Serialization and pointers Java

Tags: java, serialization

When you serialized an object does it follow pointers. Let say I have a tree data structure and the root and all other object in the tree implement serializable.  My class looks like this

class Tree
...
private Node root:
...

Will it be able to follow the root being the only explicitly declared instance variable? Will it save the whole tree even though the pointed to elements aren't members? Also when it is restored will it recreate the data structure entirely?

Comment: Java does have pointers. Hava is handling pointers and it wouldn't work without them. It is just making it difficult for the user to use them. And object references are an abstracted form of a pointer. Indeed they are implemented as those, but not specified as those in the java definition. Pointers are there, but no easy accessible pointer arithmetic or functionality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if your root object and all its fields (and all the fields in those objects, and so on) are `Serializable`, then serialization will save the entire structure (by following each pointer/reference that it finds).  The only things it won't save are any fields declared as `transient` or `static`.

Note that serialization is Java is even smart enough to handle [circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792501/does-java-serialization-work-for-cyclic-references).

Comment: I may add also that it will neither serialize any data located in any parent classes that are not serializable.

Comment: I didn't consider that, so it saves the entire inheritance hierarchy, as long as it's serializable?

Comment: There's a fair bit you can do to customize the serialization process (for instance, to handle fields in a non-serializable superclass).  This might be an interesting read:  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: @rubixibuc it will "save" the entire object graph, starting from the first serializable ancestor of your object in question.